# How to have the same view on a logo in different browser

Tags: html, css

I've made a text on a website on the top left of the page. 
When I look at it on chrome or explorer, it's perfect, the position is what I'm expecting. But on safari the button is under the logo. 
How can I fix it please without impacting the view in the other browser.

The original view should look like this "LOGO | TEXT" but here is how it is on safari.
[image]

and this is the code I used to do it.

```css
body {
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
         <i class="fa fa-navicon fa-lg"></i>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="position:relative; right:20%;" target="_blank" href="https://www.cirad.fr/">CIRAD</a>
    <span class="navbar-pipe"> | </span>
    <a style="position:relative;right:15%;text-decoration:none;color:white;font-size:36px;top:5px;" href="{% url " home " %}">AWARE</a>
</div>
```

Moreover I would like to know if there's a way to change the bottom margin of the site because I have a footer in the bottom of the page withe `position: fixed` and the company don't want to change it, but the issue is that some of the information of the game is hidden behind this footer. My idea was to change to bottom margin but it didn't change anything.

Comment: created a code snippet based on the code you have provided but the logo doesn't looks like how it is in screenshot.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your code doesn't render into something that's even similar to the picture

Comment: Because the button is located in a navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" style= "position:relative; right:20%;"target="_blank" href="https://www.cirad.fr/" >CIRAD</a>
<span class="navbar-pipe"> | </span>      
<a style="position:relative;right:15%;text-decoration:none;color:white;font-size:36px;top:5px;" href="{% url "home" %}">AWARE</a>
```

Solution:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
<a class="navbar-brand" style= "position:relative; right:20%;"target="_blank" href="https://www.cirad.fr/" >CIRAD</a>
<span class="navbar-pipe"> | </span>      
<a style="position:relative;right:15%;text-decoration:none;color:white;font-size:36px;top:5px;" href="{% url "home" %}">AWARE</a>
</div>
```